# For Schengen visa, can I be flexible with where I'll be traveling/arriving from?

Tags: international-travel, schengen-visas, europe

So basically, I am planning to travel to a few European countries later this year. However, my plan before I arrive into Europe is not very clear as of now. So for example in the given itinerary for the visa it's mentioned that I'll be coming in from London into Amsterdam and then travel across Europe, can I later come in from Istanbul (or any other country for that matter) to Amsterdam?

To sum it up,

Visa given by Netherland embassy

**Scenario 1:** London > Amsterdam > Budapest > Home Country

Can I change this scenario 2 after getting the visa and closer to travel date?

**Scenario 2:** Istanbul > Amsterdam > Budapest > Home Country

*Dates of reaching Amsterdam will remain same in both scenarios.*

Comment: In this case your itinerary **inside** the Schengen Area has not changed at all.

Comment: Do you need a visa for the UK or Turkey if you are planning on spending time in either before travelling to Amsterdam? If so, will you have the visa(s) before you submit your itinerary with your Schengen application?

Comment: Yes, correct my itinerary won't change at all. Yes, I will be needing a visa for both Turkey/UK (and most likely anywhere else I'll be). 

I won't have any of other visas before I submit my itinerary. That's the catch here. Ideally, I apply for the Schengen visa mentioning that I'll be coming in from London. But it is possible that I am not granted the UK visa for some reason. In that case, I'll have to come in from Istanbul (where visa is easy to get but I can only get it after getting the UK/Schengen visa)

Comment: If you can, mention in your Schengen visa application that you are trying for an UK visa but might need to use a second choice option instead.

Answer (score 2):

- With a Schengen visa, you **can** make minor adjustments after the visa is issued. Switching the airport of entry is exactly such a minor adjustment.
- But you **must not** misrepresent your itinerary to get that visa, even in minor details that would be a valid change *after* issue.
- What is often left unsaid is that you **should not** give the appearance of misrepresentation even with legitimate changes.

This last bullet point may be the problem. If you had many previous trips, and if your application 'looks strong,' probably no worries. If it is one of your first trips, or if your financial situation and ties to home are marginal, you should be more carful.

With your comments, I do not see any great risk here, but I'm not the one whose travel history is at risk.

Comment: Yes, certainly I am trying my best to not give any appearance of misrepresentation. My plan was to do:

Turkey: 20th July to 11th August
UK/London: 11th August to 26th August
Europe: 26th August to 20th September

Ideally, I apply for and get the Schengen visa mentioning that I'll be flying in from London. However, I still need to apply for the UK visa. If perchance, I don't manage to secure that, most probably I will have to fly in from Istanbul (or my home/work country)

Comment: Also, I would like to add that I am not changing my airport of entry. Rather, the place of departure where I'll be flying into EU from.

Comment: I agree in general with your last point, but OP will still be entering Schengen in the same country with their changed itinerary. There isn't even the appearance of misrepresentation here because the change is of no benefit in applying for the visa-misrepresenting the itinerary is usually used when the correct country to apply to would have no appointment slots or is perceived as more strict in granting visas. Changing where you fly from into Schengen doesn't make any difference.

Comment: @IamJojo45, the key thing here is that the main destination in Schengen does not change, which should prevent any suspicion of 'visa shopping' (misrepresenting the itinerary to get a consulate which is perceived as 'easier').

Comment: @MJeffryes, visiting the UK first, a high-cost, high-prestige destination, might set the mind of a visa official at ease. But I agree, it is a not very critical change. I'll edit a little to clarify that.